# Set $_FILES array manually and use move_uploaded_file function

Tags: php, file, upload

If I don't use upload form and just set `$_FILES` array I can not use of `move_uploaded_file()` function for save:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target); //false
```

How do I make this deceit!!! this means I want to set `$_FILES` manually but also I want to use `move_uploaded_file()` function too.

Is it possible?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible.  taken from **[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)**

> `$_FILES` is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This
>   simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible at all we can set the all the values manually for `$_FILES` as consider as a variable. But for moving the files the `temp_name` important.